# multiple safari windows in different spaces?

Tags: safari, osx-spaces

i was just wondering if it's possible to keep one (or more) safari windows in one space, while keeping one (or more) safari windows open in a different space.

for instance, if i'm working on spanish homework and lit homework at the same time, i'd like to keep a spanish translation website in space 1, and literary terms website in space 2.

whenever i try to do this, the safari windows all end ufp migrating to one space, instead of staying where i put them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

I normally do that. I open varous windows then I go to Space Exposé and drag each window to where i want it.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I might recommend FireFox in one space, Chrome in another, and Safari in a third...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

The default Spaces behavior, when switching applications, is to switch back to a space if that space already has open windows for that application. This is basically what you've described: If you already have a Safari window open in Space 1, switching to Safari will move you back to Space 1.

To disable this behavior, go to System Preferences -> Exposé and Spaces, select the Spaces tab, and deselect "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application"

You can also switch between spaces using ctrl + Left Arrow or ctrl + Right Arrow (See Syst.prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control)

What I need to find out is after you have set this up, to keep the browser windows in their assigned spaces after a restart. Anyone?